# How do I build docker container behind company proxy?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am trying to build a simple python based docker container. I am working at a corporate behind a proxy, on Windows 10. Below is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7.9-alpine3.11

WORKDIR ./

RUN pip install --proxy=http://XXXXXXX:8080 -r requirements.txt

COPY . /

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "application.py"]
```

But it's giving me the following errors in cmd :

```
"failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.7.9-alpine3.11: proxyconnect tcp: EOF"
```

I've tried to figure out how to configure docker's proxy, using many links but they keep referring to a file "/etc/sysconfig/docker" which I cannot find anywhere under Windows 10 or maybe I'm not looking at the right place.

Also I'm not sure this is only a proxy issue since I've seen people running into this issue without using a proxy.
I would highly appreciate anyone's help. Working at this corporate already made me spend >10 hours doing something that took me 10 minutes to do on my Mac... :(
Thank you

Comment: Is it an option to ask to unblock it?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about the most basic of Docker functionality.  Normally, it has to connect to the Docker Hub on the internet to get base images.  If you can't make this work with your proxy, you can either

1. preload your local cache with the necessary images
2. set up a Docker registry inside your firewall that contains all the images you'll need

Obviously, the easiest thing, probably by far, would be to figure out how to get Docker to connect to Docker Hub through your proxy.

In terms of getting Docker on Windows to work with your proxy, might this help? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

Here's what it says about configuring a proxy:

```
To set proxy information for docker search and docker pull, create a Windows environment variable with the name HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY, and a value of the proxy information. This can be completed with PowerShell using a command similar to this:

In PowerShell:

    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://username:password@proxy:port/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

Once the variable has been set, restart the Docker service.

In PowerShell: 

    Restart-Service docker

For more information, see Windows Configuration File on Docker.com.
```

I've also seen it mentioned that **Docker for Windows** allows you to set proxy parameters in its configuration GUI interface.

Comment: Exactly! But how do I configure my proxy is the question? https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-docker-to-use-proxy/  seems to be exactly the solution but it refers to 2 methods I don't understand:
1) "Configuring proxy variables in the /etc/sysconfig/docker file" -> Where is this 'etc' folder/ where is this directory on Windows 10?
2) "Configuring environment variables" which requires creating a 'drop-in' in this same 'etc' folder.
Long story short: where to find " /etc/sysconfig/docker" under windows 10?

Comment: You can't use the environment variable method mentioned in my answer? - This doc also mentions a configuration file: `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` - I don't know if that's the equivalent of `/etc/sysconfig/docker`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have just followed exactly what you suggested: went through all steps of the microsoft guide, set my windows environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY, also set them using the Docker GUI, and also set them using the powershell commands you suggested, and restarted Docker after that. Even with that, I get a  "Error response from daemon: Get https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: EOF" on the first step of the microsoft guide to pull a base image https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container

Comment: Wow.  Super bummer man :(. Sorry you're having so much trouble.  I hope you figure it out soon!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass proxy information in the Dockerfile.

There are predefined ARGs which can be used for this purpose.
HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
FTP_PROXY

You can pass the details when building the image

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#predefined-args

I do not see any run time dependency of your container on the Internet. So running the container will work without an issue.